# What is the timeline of Black Mirror?

Tags: timeline, black-mirror

What is the timeline of Black Mirror episodes? Most episodes have Easter eggs that somehow tie them together, and we see the various technologies in various states of development throughout the series.

Assuming these Easter eggs tie the episodes together, similar to the [Pixar Theory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113880/how-does-the-good-dinosaur-fit-into-the-pixar-theory), where do all the episodes fit in time in relation to each other?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/blackmirror/comments/59430t/definitive_black_mirror_timeline_with_date_stamps/